# SQL Azure VM Usecase for each backup type

Tags: azure, azure-vm

It seems that within the Virtual Machine category in Azure the solutions for backups become increasingly complex when compared to the PaaS options.

What is the use case for each backup solution, and what is the best practice recommendation by Microsoft when we are running a marketplace image of SQL Server within a Virtual Machine.

- Managed Backups
- Automated Backups
- Azure Recovery Services Vault
- File Snapshot backups
- Backup to URL

I am currently within an environment where a vendor has implemented their own backups into the file system, but the VM itself is being backed up into a Recovery Services Vault and I'm looking to optimise the current configuration.

Comment: Backup to a Geographically redundant storage account.  I don't trust Recovery Services or File Snapshot for live databases (they never seem to get things consistent for a database), but are good for capturing the machine state.

Comment: @JonathanFite Ok, so your recommendation is to keep the recovery vault for the VM backup, but add manual backups to a URL similar (something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15)